# Discord.js issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot but some discord.js functions seem undefined.
For example:

```
if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
               play(connection, message);
});
```

gives me:
`Cannot read property 'join' of undefined`

Comment: `message.member.voiceChannel` is undefined.

Comment: Could we see your whole code because it would really help us to help you :)

Comment: Can you run `npm list`?

Comment: voiceChannel could be `voice.channel` in newer versions

Comment: I was not using voiceChannel correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current discord.js package version does not work well with the current node version, idk why but I had the same experience so it's best that you stick with your previous versions.

Maybe that's the reason..

Answer (score 3):

There is a possible reason.

If you are using the latest version of discord.js (v12), then you do `message.member.voice.channel` rather than `message.member.voiceChannel`.

If you are using the older version of discord.js (v11), then that should be correct and I don't see why it's spitting out an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to discord.js version 12.0 and nodejs version 13.6
Solved the problem for me. Tell me if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the latest Discord version. Due to this there have been certain changes. Instead of doing `message.member.voiceChannel`, you should do `message.member.voice.channel`. Hope this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of Discord.js. If you're using v12 (Latest version), you need to do message.member.voice.channel
Try upgrading your Discord.js or you can just do
message.member.voiceChannel
You can do either one of those.
Note that v12 is more recommended because for v11, they aren't fixing any bugs now. You can also just look at discordjs.guide.